# JavaFX + JNLP different behavior on Linux and Mac

Tags: java, javafx, java-web-start

I'm writing an Java Web Start application for both Linux and OS X. It uses JavaFx for building the user interface (my main application inherits from JavaFx Application class). It runs nicely on OS X but on Linux (Ubuntu using IcedTea) the interface gets wrong. Here is:

[image: Linux (Wrong)]

[image: OSX (Right)]

My JNLP is configured as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://josericardojunior.com/Dominoes/" href="Dominoes.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Dominoes</title>
    <vendor>Universidade Federal Fluminense</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://josericardojunior.com/test/" />
    <description>Dominoes exploratory tool</description>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="3072M"/>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="8.0+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
    <jar href="libs/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar"/>                
</resources>    
<application-desc main-class="boundary.Main" />
</jnlp>
```

Does someone knows why this is happening?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please post your initial debugging.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. The application runs but the layout is not right.